# Wifi stopped working after docker installation on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, linux-mint

I have installed **Docker** following their [offical docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_one/) on my **Linux Mint** computer (running on a Mac Book Pro).

After the install the WIFI shut down and suddenly stopped working. The problem persist after having uninstalled docker.

The output of  `iwconfig` gives:

```
enx7831c1f319de  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `ip link` gives:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enx7831c1f319de: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:31:c1:f3:19:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

NB: I briefly saw in my network manager (bottom left shortcut) a "Docker bridge connection" which i deleted.

I can i get my Wifi working again - or reset everything ?

**UPDATE: Full network/config info** [wireless-info.txt dump here](https://jsfiddle.net/2mut5ncd/)

One more idea: could it be a `modprob` blacklisted module by docker or something ?

Comment: what is the result of `ip link` ?

Comment: Added the ouptut in the question..

Comment: strange can you reboot and give us the result of `ip link` and `service network-manager status` ?

Comment: No changes in output after reboot. Service network-manager is all green ` Active: active (running) since jeu. 2017-02-09 16:55:36 CET; 3min 42s ago`

Comment: Well, the WIFI switch of the left bottom shortcut has completely disappeared... (was here before the issue)

Comment: I'd want to know your bridging configuration (`brctl show`). Wouldn't be surprised if it tried to move your primary interface into a bridge -- which would be great for ethernet, not so much for wifi (many chipsets won't send traffic with other MAC addresses, which is rather essential to bridging as an approach).

Comment: Command brctl does not exist...

Comment: That said, I'm not sure this is a StackOverflow question per se. Inasmuch as Docker isn't a development-specific tool, but is also used in production environments, that puts it outside of the "unique to software development" element of site scope (as documented in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: re: brctl not existing, are you sure you were running with root's PATH (having `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` present)? I don't know Mint, but moving brctl into an optional package would surprise me, a lot. Docker not making that package a dependency when it supports bridged networking would surprise me even more.

Comment: I installed bridge utils and ran the command as root: it shows an empty table with headers bridge name, bridge_id, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135305/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-romain-bruckert).

Comment: Does `ip addr list` show your IP bound to the device?

Comment: (BTW, JSFiddle is meant for... well... JavaScript; consider using https://gist.github.com/ or http://ix.io/ or another more general-purpose ad-free pastebin in the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading your network/config I noticed the following :

```
[    6.721067] b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1)
[    6.721073] b43: probe of bcma0:1 failed with error -95
```

A `dmesg | grep b43` will confirm if there's really an error but I'll suggest to execute the following :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: Just for the record, do a `sudo reboot` to see the wifi working back again.